# Is there a way to force httpie to use '%20' instead of '+' for spaces in query parameters?

Tags: encoding, urlencode, httpie

Using httpie v2.3.0, I am interacting with a REST api that recognizes `%20` but not `+` for space encodings in the values of query parameters. Is there a way to change httpie behavior to achieve the desired behavior below?

Query:

```
http -v :9000/query/bugsigdb/jaccard_nbor_ss 'source.type==signature' \
  source=='Signature 123' e_type==Signature_Taxonomy rev_e_type==Taxonomy_Signature
```

Results in:

```
GET /query/bugsigdb/jaccard_nbor_ss?source.type=signature&source=Signature+123&e_type=Signature_Taxonomy&rev_e_type=Taxonomy_Signature HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.3.0
```

Desired result:

```
GET /query/bugsigdb/jaccard_nbor_ss?source.type=signature&source=Signature%20123&e_type=Signature_Taxonomy&rev_e_type=Taxonomy_Signature HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.3.0
```

Note the difference between `Signature+123` and `Signature%20123`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it’s not possible to instruct HTTPie to use `%20` instead of `+` for spaces when you use the `param==value` syntax. If you want to have control over this, then specifying the params as part of URL is the way to go. You can try opening a new issue for this: https://github.com/httpie/httpie/issues/new